# Rails form_for is engulfing entire new.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to place a bootstrap modal to create a model inside another model's new page. The html follows:

new.html:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Novo Parceiro</h1>
</div>

<%= render :partial => 'form' %>

<%= render :partial => "/contatos/form" %>
```

_form.html:

```
<%= form_for @parceiro, :html => { :class => "ketchup" } do |f| %>

(fields and submit here...)

<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // some javascript here OUTSIDE the form
</script>
```

But what happens when the page is loaded is that everything inside new.html, including the partial "/contatos/form" which is an ajax-able form for another model, is being rendered inside the  tag for @parceiro.

Why does Rails do this, and how do I keep my second form outside the first? As it is, I can't use AJAX because nested forms don't work very well (in fact it's wrong even for the html specifications)

[EDIT]: Issue solved, I had a div in the first form with a self closing tag (), so I changed that to a regular closing tag and it now works.

Comment: Maybe you got a html open-close tag issue. Check your code for unclosed html tags and try to enclose the `render :partial` code inside some div.

Comment: I checked for that before posting here, found no issues on that, but double checking now I noticed that I had a div with clear:both to fix some floating that I tried to close without the closing tag, using directly <div />. I changed that to use the closing tag and now it works, thanks!